# Insert newline in text file using COPY

Tags: postgresql, reporting, postgresql-copy

I want to insert a line break in a text file using copy command

I'm asked to port sqlplus scripts that generate reports from the data base in custom csv and text formats.
I'm looking for ways to implement functionalities of `sqlplus`  like:

```
set newpage
set linesize
spool <File>
ttitle left 'text....'
center 'some text....'

some queries 

exit
```

For the simple task f trying to use `copy` in `plpgsql`
I'm trying t print a multiline string to a file but the `E` mode for insert line is not working

My line:

```
COPY (SELECT CURRENT_DATE || E'\n' || 'NAME: MY NAME' || E'\n' || 'ADDRESS:ADDRESS') TO 'path/to/file.txt');
```

I tried the other way of putting the E in the beginning, didn't work too.

Can anyone help me with this and how o approach doing what sqlplus is doing in postgres ?

I'm using `debian` and `postgres 13.3`

Comment: `E'...'` in Postgres is escape string syntax, see here [Escape string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html). Please change your title and question to reflect this. Also add to your question the table schema you are copying from. Also `COPY` is for outputting data not formatted strings. Also you cannot concatenate a `date` field(CURRENT_DATE) to a string in any case.

Comment: the schema for the time being is public. 
and if Copy is for outputting data, what is the way to output frmatted strings.
for the current date the line of code in my function works just fine in putting the date with whatever string that i put after it, so unless i misinterpreted your reply i'm not sure what you want to say

Comment: Schema as in table definition.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm not using any tables in my example, i just want to be able to generate formatted text or csv dcuments using plpgsql in a similiar way to sqlplus

Comment: I have already told you that can't be done using `COPY`. You can create a straight CSV file, but that is it. If you want to create a report you will need to use something else.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver OK thanks, any suggestions ?

Comment: That is going to depend on what output format you want and what programming language(s) you are comfortable with. It is really out of the scope of a SO answer. Search on Postgres report and the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` doesn't work here, because it will escape line breaks.

You are using the client (`sqlplus`) for that in Oracle, so do the same thing in PostgreSQL and use `psql`:

```
\pset tuples_only
\pset format unaligned
\o path/to/file.txt
SELECT CURRENT_DATE || E'\n' || 'NAME: MY NAME' || E'\n' || 'ADDRESS:ADDRESS';
\q
```